# Combining NavigationDrawer and SlidingPaneLayout - SlidingPaneLayout from the right possible?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, slidingpanelayout

I'm using a `NavigationDrawer` as main menu in my app. Some of my fragments use the `SlidingPaneLayout`.

At the moment, I show the `NavigationDrawer` on the right and the `SlidingPaneLayout`on the left, always a little bit visible.

But I would like to have the `NavigationDrawer` on the left side and the `SlidingPaneLayout` on the right side (like in Hangouts) always a little bit visible.

**Question:**

I know how to get the `NavigationDrawr` to the other side, but I can't find out how (if possible) to move the `SlidingPaneLayout` to the right side? So that it slides in from the right...

**my solution**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout
    android:id="@+id/sliding_pane_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_main_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <include
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            layout="@layout/card_toast_container" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- marginLeft: set it to width - 150 in your code!!! -->

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_slider"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp" />
</android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout>
```

and use some wrapping methods like for example following, for easier and more readable code:

```
public boolean isSliderMenuShown()
{
    return !mSlidingLayout.isOpen();
}

public static void openSlider(boolean isSliderLeft, MySlidingPaneLayout slidingLayout)
{
    slidingLayout.closePane();
}

public static void closeSlider(boolean isSliderLeft, MySlidingPaneLayout slidingLayout)
{
    slidingLayout.openPane();
}
```

Comment: Hi @promo85, did get any solution for moving SlidingPaneLayout to right.. pls help me out if u have found...

Comment: I just start with an opend `SlidingPaneLayout`... And I added some code for you to my main post, which should explain, how to get the menu to right side...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set this to view inside navigation drawer:

```
android:layout_gravity="left"
```

you can try keeping it open in the start with:

```
SlidingPaneLayout sp = (SlidingPaneLayout) findViewById(R.id.spl);
sp.openPane();
```

Also keep your main content on the left and menu on the right

Comment: I know how to get the `NavigationDrawer` to the left side, my problem is the `SlidingPaneLayout`... I'll make this more clear in my question...

Comment: try calling openPane() in the start so this will behave like hangout.

Comment: I must commit, I didn't think about that, although I sometimes open activities with opened `SlidingPaneLayout`... I will have a look at the open/close callbacks and if they can be used correctly without any disadvantage... but I think this really might be a possible solution... Although I have to change the logic in my complete app for this...

Answer (score 1):

After my research and test, `android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout` can't swipe out from right to left. The only effect is swiping out from left to right.
No matter whether `android:layout_gravity=` is `start` `left` `end` or `right`.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by adding the layout direction for you Slidingpanel layout

```
layout = (SlidingPaneLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_pane_layout);
        layout.setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
```

before that make sure you have added a property  `android:supportsRtl="true"` for your manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

****Step-1****

In order to support RTL in your app, you first need to add android:supportsRtl="true" to the  element in your manifest file.

**Step-2**

Add RTL support in SlidingPaneLayout

android:layoutDirection="rtl"

**Step-3**
Add LTR support in child views of SlidingPaneLayout

android:layoutDirection="ltr"

```
    <SlidingPane
        android:id="@+id/slidingPanelLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl">

        <include
            layout="@layout/left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layoutDirection="ltr" />

        <include
            layout="@layout/view_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layoutDirection="ltr"
          />
    </SlidingPane>
```

Note: add LTR support in both left_drawer.xml, view_container.xml